# Filter data in Jquery array and count by key

Tags: jquery, filter

```
var newly = [
                {"id":"15","cm_id":"31","name":"nims","total":1},
                {"id":"15","cm_id":"61","name":"bims forum",,"total":3},
                {"id":"80","cm_id":"198","name":"rims for topic",,"total":2}
                ];
```

I want to filter above array filter by id and find count of total values
Ex: id-> 15 total -> 4

please advice how to use filter and reduce together to sort array by an id and count totals for each id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an object that you set the id value as keys and sum of total as values

```js
var newly = [
                {"id":"15","cm_id":"31","name":"nims","total":1},
                {"id":"15","cm_id":"61","name":"bims forum","total":3},
                {"id":"80","cm_id":"198","name":"rims for topic","total":2}
                ];
                
 var idTotals = {};
 
 newly.forEach(({id, total}) => idTotals[id] = (idTotals[id] || 0) + total)
 
 console.log(idTotals)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method

```js
var totalCount = {};
var newly = [
                {"id":"15","cm_id":"31","name":"nims","total":1},
                {"id":"15","cm_id":"61","name":"bims forum","total":3},
                {"id":"80","cm_id":"198","name":"rims for topic","total":2}
            ];

for(const {id,total} of newly) {
    totalCount[id] = (id in totalCount) ? totalCount[id]+=total : total
}  

for(const id in totalCount){
    console.log(`id-> ${id} total -> ${totalCount[id]}`)
}
```